# Huge gap in increment value of identity column

Tags: sql, database, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have created a table with an identity column. When I insert values in that table, Identity column shows huge gap of increment in between the values. Identity value jumps from 6 to 10001. This is the output ordered by Department id:

[Output Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw1mE.jpg)

This is table I have created:

```
Create Table STG2.Department
(
    DepartmentID int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1  Cycle),
    Name varchar(100),
    GroupName varchar(100)
)
PRIMARY INDEX (DepartmentID);
```

This is how I am inserting values into the `Department` table:

```
insert into STG2.Department (Name, GroupName)
    Select Distinct
        Department, GroupName 
    from DP_STG.HR;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it perhaps be that there's a process that on a regular interval refreshes data in that Department table. But instead of using MERGE or UPDATE existing & INSERT new, that it simple does it by DELETE and INSERT?  If you have foreign keys to that Department table then that wouldn't be a good method to use. But it would explain the gaps. The identity increases with each insert. It doesn't automatically decrease on deletion.

Comment: I wonder what the MAXVALUE would be when using CYCLE without setting the MAXVALUE.

Comment: @LukStorms: The MaxValue will be based on the maximum value of the data type, in case of INT 2.147.483.647 (similar for MinValue)

Comment: @dnoeth Thx for that info. Heh, then it would appear that it'll be a while till those deleted DepartmentId's get recycled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

What you are doing wrong is worrying about gaps in the identity column.  These are a natural part of using databases. The most typical reasons are due to `delete` or failed `insert`s. The only guarantee (I think) is that the numbers are increasing and not duplicated.

In your case, my guess is that Teradata is reserving a bunch of numbers for some good reasons -- for parallelism or some other efficiency (I know SQL Server does this). The gaps will cause no harm, and the order of the inserts should be pretty-well preserved.

Maintaining gapless identity columns is a *huge* overhead for a database, particularly a powerful, parallel database such as Teradata. In essence, it means that each insert has to complete all queries on the table, lock the table, find the maximum value, add one, and use that. The people who write databases know what a performance killer this is and have looser requirements for such columns.

Comment: So very very true.  In the case of Teradata, each amp basically has a range of values for an identity value.  To grossly oversimply, amp 1 might get 1-1000, amp 2 1001-2000, amp3 2001-3000. ( I think it's really 100k per amp, but I'm too lazy to type all those 0s.)  There's a little more to it than this, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @Andrew Your comment is actually the best answer.  The real reason is that teradata does not process records sequentially but in parallel.  So there is no reason to expect them to be sequentially numbered

Comment: What if I want to store results in only one amp? let say if my result-set is small.

Comment: That's not how Teradata works. There's a ton of information about this on the internet. Understanding that is absolutely critical to be successful.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated the gaps are due to each AMP (the logical Processing Unit of Teradata to have MPP) has each own range of IDs. So it's not wrong to have these gaps but it's by design.

If you rely on IDs without gaps (for any reason), you have to do by your own. Either before loading in your ETL process or after/during loading and define "ID = ROW_NUMBER() + MAX(ID)" (pseudo code).