# In Entity Framework id value doesn't get incremented by 1, but by 1000?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In the following table, you can see that `billid` column is increased by 1000 at 10th row.

[image]

The code to generate new `bill` is as follows:

```
private void NewBill()
{
    var bill = new Bill
        {
            BillDate = DateTime.Now,
            InUse = true,
            Paid = false,
            TableId = _tableId,
            UserId = frmLogIn.LoggedInUserId
        };

    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        context.Bills.Add(bill);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Why it does not get incremented by just 1 ?

I am using EF6 with SQL Server 2017 Express edition.

Comment: Why do you care? It has nothing to do with EF. It is the db server that does this and you cannot control it.

Comment: Did you have a look at your table definition??

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with EF - it's a **feature** in SQL Server - [read more about here on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column)

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to various reasons as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426157/huge-gap-in-increment-value-of-identity-column) as pointed out by @CodingYoshi. To avoid such mishaps, you could opt to generate the BillId that you can almost be sure to be sequential by fetching the last BillId and incremeting it by 1.

You could write a function like below

```
public int NextId()
{
    int lastId = 0;

    var billsFromStore = _context.Bills;

    if (billsFromStore.Any())
    {
        var idsFromStore = _context.Bills.Select(x => x.BillId);

        lastId = idsFromStore.Max();
    }

    return ++lastId;
}
```

you may want to use a [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) to prevent different thread incrementing the value

Comment: And then get all sorts of race conditions as soon as the code runs in production.

Comment: Why would you do this, to gain what? Also imagine this happens and it will: one thread gets next id of 21, and releases the lock but has more work to do before inserting record into table. Now another thread asks for id, it will also get 21. Boom!